# Spring filter: obtain servlet url-pattern

Tags: java, spring, rest, servlets, mapping

Imagine I have defined these REST endpoints:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/user")
@RestController
public class ConfigUserController {

    [...]
    
    @GetMapping(path = "/variables/")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Variable>> getAllVariables(...)
        [...]
    }
    
    @GetMapping(path = "/variables/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<Variable> getVariableByName(...)
        [...]
    }
    
    @PutMapping(path = "/variables/{name}/{value}")
    public ResponseEntity<Variable> setVariableByName(...)
        [...]
    }
}
```

I've defined two filter (logging and authorization), inside the filters I want to get the url-patter which matched current request. Using the example above:

- if the request was a GET to /variables, I want "/variables"
- if the request was a GET to /variables/myfancyname, I want "/variables/{name}"
- if the request was a PUT to /variables/myfancyname/myvalue, I want "/variables/{name}/{value}"

Basically what I need is to get the path defined in the mapping annotation inside the doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) method of my filters.

Ideally I want to have do the possibility to access the url-pattern value in my filter like this:

```
@Component
@Order(3)
public class MyAuthorizationRequestFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    [...]
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // here I get the value
        String urlPattern = request.useSomeMethod().toGetUrlPattern();
        [...]
        boolean auth = false;
        // here I do stuff
        [...]
        // finally let's see if the user is authorized
        if (auth) {
            chain.doFilter(request, responde);
        } else {
            throw SomeAuthorizationError();
        }
    }
    [...]
}
```

I've been searching but I wasn't able to find a working solution.

If it's possible I prefer not to scan for collections or web.xml files (which I don't have), nor using reflections, because the code will be executed every time the filter get triggered and I don't want to affect performance.

Links or suggestions are welcome.

EDIT: added details, addes filter example cose

Answer (score 6):

### 1. Solution using  Servlet filter(after Filter doFilter) ## Here, Not recommending this solution.

Filters intercept requests before they reach the DispatcherServlet, making them ideal for coarse-grained tasks such as:

- Authentication
- Logging and auditing
- Image and data compression
- Any functionality we want to be decoupled from Spring MVC

**Note*** Do the **doFilter** first before trying to do the call to **getAttribute**

**Your Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/user")
@RestController
public class ConfigUserController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/variables/")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Variable>> getAllVariables() {
        return null;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/variables/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<Variable> getVariableByName(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Variable>(new Variable(name), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping(path = "/variables/{name}/{value}")
    public ResponseEntity<Variable> setVariableByName() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Custom Filter**

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CustomFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO
        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            String pattern = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);
            System.out.println("Request template is, " + pattern);
        }
    }

}
```

**O/P:**

```
 Request template is, /user/variables/{name}
```

**Note*** Do the chain.doFilter first before trying to do the call to getAttribute

---

### 2. Solution using Interceptor

HandlerIntercepors intercepts requests between the DispatcherServlet and our Controllers. This is done within the Spring MVC framework, providing access to the Handler and ModelAndView objects.

**Custom Interceptor**

```
@Component
public class LoggerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object, Exception arg3)
            throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object, ModelAndView model)
            throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object) throws Exception {
        String path = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);
        System.out.println("path : " + path);
        return true;
    }}
```

**Register it with InterceptorRegistry**

```
@Component
public class CustomServiceInterceptorAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
   @Autowired
   LoggerInterceptor loggerInterceptor;

   @Override
   public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
      registry.addInterceptor(loggerInterceptor);
   }
}
```

[image]

### 3. Solution using  Java Reflection API.

Beans that are singleton-scoped and set to be pre-instantiated (the default) are created when the container is created. It's a one time process, you don't worry about the performance.

You may pre-scan all @RequestMapping,@GetMapping, @PostMApping etc.. annotations, keep it and then in the filter match the pattern to get the desired result.

Here is the sample

**Bean**

```
@Component
public class Config {

    public List<String> getPatterns() throws ClassNotFoundException {

        List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
        Class clazz = Class.forName("com.example.demo.controller.ConfigUserController"); // or list of controllers,
                                                                                            // //you can iterate that
                                                                                            // list
        for (Method method : clazz.getMethods()) {
            for (Annotation annotation : method.getDeclaredAnnotations()) {
                if (annotation.toString().contains("GetMapping")) {
                    str.add(annotation.toString());
                    System.out.println("Annotation is..." + annotation.toString());
                }
                if (annotation.toString().contains("PutMapping")) {
                    str.add(annotation.toString());
                    System.out.println("Annotation is..." + annotation.toString());
                }
                if (annotation.toString().contains("PostMapping")) {
                    str.add(annotation.toString());
                    System.out.println("Annotation is..." + annotation.toString());
                }
            }
        }

        return str;

    }
```

**Custom Filter**

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CustomFilter implements Filter {
    @Autowired
    Config con;
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO
        try {
            //filter match the pattern to get the desired result
            System.out.println(con.getPatterns());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: I've tried something like that but I'm not sure it's ok to do a chain.doFilter() inside for example an authentication or authorization filter, and if I omit that part most of the attributes are null. maybe I'm wrong and it's ok?

Comment: If possible can you add your security/logging filters?

Comment: I've edited my question with a filter example

Comment: getAttribute value will be null if you are trying to call before doFilter.

Comment: Also using Java reflection API I added one solution with the help of @Bean. Beans that are singleton-scoped and set to be pre-instantiated (the default) are created when the container is created.

Comment: Your solution put me on the right path, I've endend creating a custom authorization filter with a `Set<RequestMappingInfo> patterns`,that gets populated in the `ContextRefreshedEvent`, so when I'm in the filter I can iterate over the RequestMappingInfo and use `getMatchingCondition(HttpRequest)` to get which mapping will be used and then `getPatternsCondition` to access the pattern

Answer (score 2):

Updating the answer to use `GenericFilterBean.doFilter` as per the question asked.
You can do this by adding a finally clause. This is needed since you need to do `chain.doFilter(request, response)` first before calling `request.getAttribute` because the attribute is not set until later in the lifecycle of the request. So if you are trying to do some operations based on incoming uri template, subclassing **GenericFilterBean** may not be the right choice here since you need to call chain.doFilter first.

```
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            //Do something
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
         String pathTemplate = (String) 
request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);
         System.out.println("Incoming Request path Template from Generic Filter : " + pathTemplate);
}


}
```

**Alternate options:**

Assuming that you are using spring web here.
You can define an `HandlerInterceptor` and register it with `InterceptorRegistry`.

```
@Component
public class LogPathTemplateInterceptor
        implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object) throws Exception {
        String pathTemplate = (String)request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);
        System.out.println("Incoming Request path Template : " + pathTemplate);
        return true;
    }
}
```

After defining this, register it with InterceptorRegistry. See how the path pattern added to the interceptor.

```
@Configuration
public class InterceptorConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private LogPathTemplateInterceptor logInterceptor;
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(logInterceptor)
                .addPathPatterns("/variables/**");
    }
}
```

This should log the request template path instead of path with variables.

Comment: Thanks, that interesting, but what if I want to access the template path inside a FilterBean, inside the doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) method? Is there any possibility?

Comment: @moretti.fabio updated my answer